# How to use the unpack function in the struct module in python

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I am using unpack to parse a piece of data, this is a byte stream in it
`b'\xc0\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`, I removed the first eight bytes, leaving 28 bytes, how should I parse them.The following is the data coding structure diagram.
[image: coding structure]

This is my code:

```
import struct
hex_string = "c0 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 e8 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e8 03 00 00"

hex_bytes = bytes.fromhex(hex_string.replace(" ", ""))
print(len(hex_bytes))
print(struct.calcsize("IIIQQ"))

length, message_type, data_count, cumulative_count, timestamp = struct.unpack('IIIQQ', hex_bytes[:28])

print("Length:", length)
print("Message Type:", message_type)
print("Data Count:", data_count)
print("Cumulative Count:", cumulative_count)
print("Timestamp:", timestamp)
```

But always the error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 32 bytes
```

I've looked up a lot of information in the evening, but I can't solve it. If anyone can help, thank you in advance

Comment: In the default mode, pad bytes are added for proper alignment of the struct items. Use `"=IIIQQ"` as format specifier or better `"=IIIQd"` according to the shown documentation. Instead of the equal sign you can use another prefix depending on the endianness.